# highlight in elasticsearch query? how to highlight two fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

my search field is one ,but I need to highlight two fields in a document? how can I achieve this
Ex:
my search query is `match:{"file":"hello"}`
I want to highlight email field also

Comment: Maybe show your complete query with highlights and everything. You can definitely add more than one fields in the `highlight.fields` section

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `require_field_match` value to `false` as by default, only fields that contains a query match are highlighted.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "file": "hello"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "require_field_match": "false",
    "fields": {
      "title": {},
      "email": {}
    }
  }
}
```